# C++ call member method vs normal function overhead

Tags: c++, performance

Suppose whatever C++ class that performs an operation like this:

```
void MyClass::operation()
{
    // final sum it's just a class member
    finalSum = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        if (i % 2 = 0)
            finalSum += 2;
        else
            finalSum += 1;
}
```

Instead of write a bunch of operations inside just one method, you refactor part of that calculations to a new method, so code now looks like this:

```
void MyClass::operation()
{
    // finalSum it's just a class member
    finalSum = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        calculateIncrement(i);
}

MyClass::calculateIncrement(int i)
{
    if (i % 2 = 0)
        finalSum += 2;
    else
        finalSum += 1;
}
```

So, two questions:

- There's a little bit of overhead for make that `method call`? It's really relevant?
- It's cheaper (in terms of memory and CPU usage) to call a method of an instance that
  calling an external function (any non-member fn that performns the same operation than `calculateIncrement()`, but with a return value?
- What if you pass the instance of your object by non-const reference or pointer to that
  external function? It's the overhead the same?

Code it's minimal, but you can argue with more complicated values that the language primitives, and suppose larger and complicated calculations than the proposed above.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you mean "overhead". And that you want to pass `i` to `calculateIncrement`.

Comment: This is a huge amount of overhead, given that this calculation is just a simple, but an obfuscated, mathematical formula, no loop required. Getting rid of the loop, in place of a single expression, will optimize things far more than an eliminated function call.

Comment: the more expensive the computations the less will be the impact of a function call. When in doubt you need to measure. There is no universal truth when it comes to performance.

Comment: write code to be readable. Next is correctness (your code is not correct). Only when you have working correct code it is time to worry about performance

Comment: There is a thing called function inlining.  More than likely the optimizer ran by your compiler will do that and completely remove the function call and place the functions code directly in the calling function.

Comment: frankly it is pointless to discuss performance and optimizations in the blue. For your concrete example the best would be to write `finalSum = 150;` everything else can be considered obfuscation and uncessary complexity. For a different example there will be a different way to simplify the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do premature optimization. Correctness is much more important than performance. The fastest code is worth nothing when it does not compile or produce wrong output.

Write code to be readable. Readable code is easier to test, debug and to refactor. Once you have working correct code you can measure to see where are the bottlenecks.

Anyhow, compilers are smart enough to see the pattern of loops similar to this one:

```
 int sum = 0;
 for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i) sum += i;
```

Knowing this, I changed your calculations to this (without this transformation I didn't get the desired output):

```
int main() {
        // final sum it's just a class member
    int finalSum = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i+=2)
            finalSum += 2;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i+=2) 
            finalSum += 1;
    return finalSum;
}
```

Turned on optimizations (`-O3`) to get [as a result](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7Gerq78x):

```
main:
        mov     eax, 150
        ret
```

There is no need to write a loop and no need to call a function. Even though I did write two loops in the code, the compiler was smart enough to see that the final result can be determined at compile time. This is the kind of optimizations that make C++ code run fast. Human-driven optimizations must always be based on profiling and measurements, and it is really hard to beat a good compiler. Though in this case you could have noticed that the final result is just `150` and that there is no need for the loop.

Conclusion: Write code to be simple and readable. The code you posted effectively assigns 150 to `finalSum` and the most simple way to express this is `finalSum = 150;`.

You may argue that I missed the point of the question. But my point is that details matter. Different code will have different opportunities to make it simpler and more expressive. It is difficult/impossible to make a general statement about whether a function call introduces too much overhead. Anyhow the compiler is much better at making this decision. It may inline the call or not when it sees that it will be worth it.

Comment: Mmmm... that's a really interesting answer. But I am trying to be more generic than that concrete piece of code. Was assumible to have expensive calculations, but you're right. The more expensive the calculation, the less impact by the function call. Also, probably the compiler can inline most of those calls probably. But the real question is, there's real difference in terms on overhead when you call a method over a non member function? I mean, consider no option to make the calculation at compile time (neither constexpr or consteval) or inline code to avoid the overhead call.

Comment: By the way, I am totally agree with you. In 2022, write code that it's understandable and mantainable it's really a much better choice that make any optimization. Yes, compilers are usually smarter than us, and it's translations to the final target could also be more impacted for the architecture against you're compiling that any "upgrade to increase the performance in your code". So, compiler wins almost everything. The initial question it's just a curiosity based question.

Comment: @AlexVergara "But the real question is, there's real difference in terms on overhead when you call a method over a non member function?" see edit. And consider that it depends on details of the code. In the example you did post there is no need for the function call in the first place. In other code the compiler might inline the function call while in other code it might not, because the compiler knows much better what is good for performance. And when it is not you can only find out by profiling and measuring

Comment: @AlexVergara too see what I mean: https://godbolt.org/z/P7xjabnqh. There is no function call. However, this does not imply anything for the general case. The only thing one can conclude from this is that gcc in this version with that flags produces that output (which has the function call optimized away)